# In VB.NET, how can you toggle between whether your own or another process is in front on the screen?

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-7, process, window

This is not a duplicate.  There are many other questions similar to this, but none of their answers are working for me, not even in Hello World apps.

Essentially I have a VB.NET program and an Adobe AIR program, and I need the VB.NET program to be able to toggle which one is in front of the other.  I've been researching APIs for doing things like this in VB.NET, but none of them have been panning out.  I've even reduced it to a Hello World program which toggles between itself and another .NET executable, but the most it will ever do is flicker orange on the Windows 7 taskbar at the bottom of the screen; whichever executable is in front will simply stay there regardless.

Most of the APIs I've seen on the Internet for this use user32.dll (this is a 32-bit machine, by the way), and they use functions like ShowWindow, SetForegroundWindow, and other kinds of things like that.  Here is but one example that has been tried:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal pHWND As IntPtr) As _
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    Private m_hwndSelf As IntPtr = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
    Private m_procApp As Process

    Private m_blnFlag As Boolean = True

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim prInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("somePath/someProg.exe", "")
        prInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        m_procApp = Process.Start(prInfo)

        Timer1.Interval = 5000
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If m_blnFlag Then
            SetForegroundWindow(m_procApp.MainWindowHandle)
        Else
            SetForegroundWindow(m_hwndSelf)
        End If
        m_blnFlag = Not m_blnFlag
    End Sub
End Class
```

This can't be rocket science, and it's probably a mistake I'm making, but I do not see an adequate explanation when searching forums and the like.  Why is this program not toggling which window is in front?  Why does it simply flicker orange?  Other, related functions don't seem to be working either, and neither do other ways of trying to get window handles, so what's wrong in general with my code?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay in how I was attempting to get the window handle.  Instead of using `Process.MainWindowHandle`, I should've been using `FindWindow(String, String)` (which is in user32.dll).  In particular:

```
FindWindow(Nothing, "Program Name in the Taskbar")
```

Technically this hasn't been verified with using `SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr)`, but it has been verified with another user32.dll function I was trying out earlier, `ShowWindow(IntPtr, Integer)`.